# A quadratic system with two solutions which may be solved with numeric coefficients, but not with symbolic ones

Tags: equation-solving, eigenvalues

The system below may be solved using the observation that the second and third equation admit solution (*,0,0,*); alternatively, the determinant of these two equations must be 0. `Mathematica` 11.3 succeeds with a numeric instance

```
s1 = \[CapitalLambda] - \[Beta] s i + Subscript[\[Gamma], r] r - 
   Subscript[\[Gamma], s] s - \[Mu] s;
e1 = \[Beta] s i - e (Subscript[\[Gamma], e] + \[Mu]);
i1 =  e Subscript[\[Gamma], e] - \[Gamma] i - (\[Mu] + \[Nu]) i;
r1 = \[Gamma] i - Subscript[\[Gamma], r] r + 
   Subscript[\[Gamma], s] s - \[Mu] r;
dyn = {s1, e1, i1, r1}
vz = {0, 0, 0, 0};
eq = Thread[dyn == vz]
cb = { \[Beta] -> 5, \[Gamma] -> 1/2, \[Mu] -> \[CapitalLambda], 
   Subscript[\[Gamma], r] -> 1/6,  Subscript[\[Gamma], s] -> 1/100, 
   Subscript[\[Gamma], e] -> 1/100, \[CapitalLambda] -> 
    40/400, \[Nu] -> 
    Subscript[\[Gamma], r] (1 + \[Gamma]/\[CapitalLambda]) - 1/10};
```

es = FullSimplify[Solve[(eq //. cb), {s, e, i, r}]]

but does not succeed with a symbolic instance, even after adding positivity assumptions

```
    cp = {\[Beta] > 0, \[CapitalLambda] > 0, \[Nu] > 0, \[Gamma] > 
    0, \[Mu] > 0, Subscript[\[Gamma], e] > 0, 
   Subscript[\[Gamma], r] > 0};
es = FullSimplify[Solve[eq~Join~cp, {s, e, i, r}]]
```

Is there a better trick  to solve the symbolic case?

Answer (score 1):

Without subscribts the equation is solved symbollically

```
Solve[{-i s \[Beta] + \[CapitalLambda] - s \[Mu]+ r \[Gamma]r - s \[Gamma]s == 0, 
i s \[Beta] - e (\[Mu] + \[Gamma]e) ==0, 
-i \[Gamma] - i (\[Mu] + \[Nu]) + e \[Gamma]e ==0, 
i \[Gamma] - r \[Mu] - r \[Gamma]r + s \[Gamma]s== 0}, {e, s, r,i}]
```

Comment: This is useful, but I would like also to know when it is recommended to use subscripts (which are pretty convenient), and when to avoid them :)

Comment: I  usually prefer indexed variables instead of subscripts. If you like subscripts it's possible to display indexed variables as subscripts using `Format[ a[s_underscore]] := Subscript[a, s]`